# How to set up a long running Django command in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, cron

I have recently moved my site to Google Cloud Run.

The problem is I also need to move a couple of cron jobs that run a Django command every day inside a container. What is the preferred way of doing this if I don't want to pay for a full Kubernetes cluster with always running node instances?

I would like the task to run and then spin the server down, just as Cloud Run does when I get an incoming request. I have searched through all the documentation, but I am having trouble in finding the correct solution for long running tasks inside containers that do not require an underlying server in Google Cloud.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is long running? Consider App Engine or Cloud Run and a script to launch a Compute Engine with Container OS for tasks that take more than 10 minutes. Once the task completes call another App Engine or Cloud Run service that will shutdown Compute Engine. This will give you high horsepower with managed costs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cloud Run** request timeout limit is ***15 minutes***.

**Cloud Functions** function timeout limit is ***540 seconds***.

For *long-running* tasks *spinning up and down **Compute Instance** when needed* would be more preferred option.

---

An example of how to schedule, ***run and stop Compute Instances automatically*** is nicely explained here: 
[Scheduling compute instances with Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule)

In brief: Actual instance start / stop is performed by `Cloud Functions`. `Cloud Scheduler` on timetable publishes required tasks to `Cloud Pub/Sub` queue which triggers these functions. Your code at the end of main logic can also publish message to `Cloud Pub/Sub` to run `Stop this instance` task.

---

How to process task in Django?

- it can be same ***django app*** started with wsgi server to process incoming requests (like regular django site) but wth increased request / response / other timeouts, long wsgi worker life ... - in this case task is regular http request to django view
- it can be just one ***script*** (or ***django management command***) run at cloud instance startup to just automatically execute one task
- you may also want to pass *additional arguments* for the task, in this case you can publish to `Cloud Pub/Sub` one `Start instance` task, and one `main logic` task with custom arguments and make your code pull from `Pub/Sub` first
- more django-native - use [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) and start celery worker as separate `Compute Instance`

---

One possisble option of how to use just one Celery worker without all other parts (i.e. broker (there is no official built-in Cloud Pub/Sub support)) and pull/push tasks to/from Cloud Pub/Sub:

- run celery worker with [dummy filesystem broker](https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/07/03/simple-celery-setup/)
- add target method as `@periodic_task` to run i.e. every 30 seconds
- at the start of the task - subscribe to Cloud Pub/Sub queue, check for new task, receive one and start processing
- at the and of the task - publish to Cloud Pub/Sub results and a call to `Stop this instance`

---

There is also **Cloud Tasks** (timeout limit: with auto-startup - ***10 minutes***, manual startup - ***24 hours***) as a Cloud Run addition for asynchronous tasks, but in this case Cloud Pub/Sub is more suitable.